# Java XML - standalone attribute added

Tags: java, xml

I was writing a test case for one of my XML parsing methods.
The goal is to create a org.w3c.dom.Document from a string, then convert it back to string and compare it with the original input.

I have the following string as my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test>
    <test-node>${value}</test-node>
    <a a1="a1V">
       <a2 a2="a2V"/>
       <a3 c1="a3V"/>
    </a>
    <b b1="b1V"/>
    <c c1="c1V">
       <c2 b1="c2V"/>
    </c>
</test>
```

It is converted from String to Document using this method:

```
public static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(final String xmlString) throws IOException, SAXException {
    try {
        return BUILDER_FACTORY.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

For the conversion back to String I use this method:

```
public static String convertNodeToString(final Node n) {
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    try {
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(n), new StreamResult(writer));

        return writer.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I run the test case, it fails because of this:

```
Expected :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><test><test-node>${value}</test-node><a a1="a1V">   <a2 a2="a2V"/>   <a3 c1="a3V"/></a><b b1="b1V"/><c c1="c1V">   <c2 b1="c2V"/></c></test>

Actual   :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><test><test-node>${value}</test-node><a a1="a1V">   <a2 a2="a2V"/>   <a3 c1="a3V"/></a><b b1="b1V"/><c c1="c1V">   <c2 b1="c2V"/></c></test>
```

**The problem is the standalone="no"**

For some reason it is adding standalone="no" to the header which fails my test case.
Now i know i could remove it by setting `document.setXmlStandalone(true);`.

That would solve the case as long as my input does not specify standalone="no".

**How can I achieve that it is not added or changed in any case?**

Answer (score 0):

Set standalone flag on your document instance

```
doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

before calling `convertNodeToString()`

Comment: Won't this just override the value if it was previously set to standalone="no" in the string?

Comment: No, for setting there a value you'll need to call `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");`. Java DOM API is a bit entangled.

Comment: I've tried it. Works with standalone="no". With standalone="yes" in the string this happens...
`Expected :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>`

`Actual   :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`